# Build find command from arguments

Tags: bash, shell-script, find, zsh

I often need to find a file, but I'm not sure what the name is, something like this:

```
$ find -iname '*foo*' -o -iname '*bar*' -o -iname '*blah*'
```

This is a little tedious. I'd like to create an alias that's easier to use, like this:

```
$ findany foo bar blah
```

Here's my attempt:

```
findany() {
    args=("-iname" "'*$1*'")
    shift

    while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
        args+=("-o" "-iname" "'*$1*'")
        shift
    done

    find ${args[@]}
}
```

The problem is it never yields any results, even though the files are right there:

```
$ ls
bar.txt  blah.txt  foo.txt

$ findany foo bar blah
# nothing
```

If I add `echo` in front of the command, it looks correct:

```
$ findany foo bar blah                     
find -iname '*foo*' -o -iname '*bar*' -o -iname '*blah*'
```

And if I copy the output above and run it, it works fine:

```
$ find -iname '*foo*' -o -iname '*bar*' -o -iname '*blah*'
./bar.txt
./foo.txt
./blah.txt
```

I figure it has to do with argument splitting or quotes but I'm not sure how to debug it.

I normally use zsh but I verified the same behavior in bash.

Comment: related: [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946/170373)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were very close! But for some reason you'd included single quotes in the file names themselves, so they'd never match.

Also you must quote `"${args[@]}"` to have it work properly. Otherwise it's subject to word splitting, and any globs will expand in the shell before `find` sees them.

Try this instead (specifically for `bash`):

```bash
findany() {
    local args=('-iname' "*$1*")
    shift

    while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
        args+=('-o' '-iname' "*$1*")
        shift
    done

    find . "${args[@]}"
}
```

Comment: I thought I needed the single quotes to prevent the shell from expanding the glob pattern.

Comment: @BigMcLargeHuge, double quotes already do stop globbing. Even if they didn't, those single quotes you had there, were part of a double-quoted string, so they don't work as quotes (e.g. `"'$foo'"` will still expand the variable). The syntax for putting words in an array is exactly the same as what you'd use when running a command, e.g. if `find ... -o -iname '*blah*'` works as a command, then `array=(-o -iname '*blah*')` works as an array assignment.

Comment: Note that in zsh, you don't need to quote `${args[@]}` for it to work properly. You can also write it `$args[@]` or `$args`. All 3 would discard empty elements which `"$args[@]"` would prevent, but having empty elements here would not make sense.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thank you for the `zsh` comparison. I was responding to the `bash` tag; happy to qualify the code to identify this if it's important

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas other than for consistency what's the reason you'd prefer `"$#"` over a plain `#$`? Myself, I don't tend to quote numeric values

Comment: See [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/171347). Specifically the *What about [ $# -gt 1 ]* section.

Comment: Note the OP mention they're using `zsh`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas but tagged as `bash`

Comment: Tagged both zsh and bash.

Answer (score 4):

With zsh, you could just use:

```
set -o extendedglob # usually in your ~/.zshrc, here used for (#i) for
                    # case insensitive matching
```

```
print -rC1 -- **/*(#i)(foo|bar|blah)*(ND)
```

To build that pattern from an array, you can use the `j[|]` parameter  expansion flag to join the elements of the array with `|` combined with either the  `~` parameter expansion flag so that that `|` be treated as a glob pattern operator, or with the `~` parameter expansion operator so that any wildcard character in the joined string (even those found in array elements) are treated as patterns.

```
findany1() print -rC1 -- **/*(#i)(${(~j[|])argv})*(ND)
```

Or:

```
findany2() print -rC1 -- **/*(#i)(${(j[|])~argv})*(ND)
```

For instance `findany1 '??'` would find the files whose name contains `??` while `findany2` would find the files whose name contains at least 2 characters. You'd need `findany2 '\?\?'` or `findany2 '[?][?]'` to find the files whose name contains `??` with `findany2`.

To make the same distinction with `find`, that'd be:

```
findany2() (
  for arg do
    argv+=( -o -iname "$arg" )
    shift
  done
  shift
  find . "$@"
)
```

```
findany1() (
  set -o extendedglob
  for arg do
    argv+=( -o -iname "${arg//(#m)[][\\?*]/\\$MATCH}" )
    shift
  done
  shift
  find . "$@"
)
```

Where we escape the wildcards recognised by `find` (`?`, `*`, `[...]` and `\`) with `\` (the only quoting operator supported by `find`/`fnmatch()`).

Comment: oooooh, `[|]`is awesome!

Comment: What the... how does `for arg do` work without `in $@`?

Comment: Oh, I see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73134775

Answer (score 1):

```
$ find -iname '*foo*' -o -iname '*bar*' -o -iname '*blah*'
```

that's one way to go about it, but frankly, it is result-wise similar to

```bash
shopt -s globstar  ## enable recursive globbing operator **
shopt -s extglob   ## enable (|) pattern lists
shopt -s nocasematch  ## take a guess!

echo **/*@(foo|bar|blah)*
```

(but it does that without help of `find`).

We can very quickly build a shell script from that.

```bash
#! /bin/bash -
shopt -s globstar  ## enable recursive globbing operator **
shopt -s extglob   ## enable (|) pattern lists
shopt -s nullglob  ## don't error if nothing matches
shopt -s nocasematch  ## take a guess!

IFS='|' # "$*" joins with the first character of IFS
pattern="**/*@(${*})*"

IFS= # do globbing but not splitting upon unquoted expansion:
matches=( $pattern )

for element in "${matches[@]}"; do
  printf '%s\n' "${element}"
done
```

If you want to have it as a function, just put `pattern=…` to `done` in a function declaration.

Comment: Interesting approach. I've never thought of using `echo` to list files. I'm not sure how to translate those bash options into zsh ones, and `echo **/*+(foo|bar|blah)*` returns "no matches found", but it works if I remove the `+`.

Comment: but `*(pattern1|pattern2|pattern3)*` means "zero or more matches of either pattern1, pattern2 or pattern3", and "zero matches" is probably not what you want :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller `*(...)` and `+(...)` are ksh operators. Here, in ksh (or `bash -O extglob`), you'd want `@(a|b)` rather than `+(a|b)`. The zsh equivalent is `(a|b)` (and the equivalent of `+(a|b)` would be `(a|b)##` with `extendedglob`). Here with bash/ksh, you'd also need to disable word splitting which is another side effect of leaving a parameter expansion unquoted. In any case, `$match` (best not to use that variable in zsh as it has a special meaning there similar to bash's `$BASH_REMATCH`) should be quoted in ksh/bash.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas hope I got the place where I need to quote right. (also, to avoid confusion, renamed $match and $matcher) How would I disable word splitting in this context?

Comment: Marcus, See edit.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas aaaaaaaaah! thanks!