# Is it possible to run find command from a bash script where the multiple name filters comes from a file?

Tags: bash, find, filenames

I'm trying to have some tracking on a folder and wanted to use the find -name filters from a file.
So I've prepared a file called filter_files that contains the filter, for example:

```
cat filter_files:
-name "a.txt" -o -name "b.txt"
```

I've tried running the find command and add the mentioned filter, but it returns nothing, if I write the content of the file and paste it into a find command it succeeds.

The relevant lines from my bash file are:

```
local filter=$(cat $filter_files)
find_files=$(find "$path" -type f \( $filter \) )
```

Can you please explain to me if I can do what I want?
And if yes, how can I make it work?

Comment: avij, is it always a name based filter (i.e. "This name" or "that name" or "some other name")?

Comment: It seems quite similar to [Build find command from arguments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/766709/100397), and the same caveats apply here as there

Comment: @ChrisDavies Yes, it's always name name-based filter, without regex or other fancy stuff.
I've tried to use the same solution as you added in the link, for now I still haven't manage it to work, but I'm trying

Comment: Avij, take [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/766720/100397) if you're using `bash` as your shell. The function then gets used with one or more quoted names. For example `findany 'a.txt' 'b.txt'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the file contains

```
-name "a.txt" -o -name "b.txt"
```

and you run

```
find "$path" -type f \( $(cat file) \)
```

Then what happens is that the shell runs the output from `cat` through word splitting, resulting in the arguments `-name`, `"a.txt"`, `-o`, `-name`, and `"b.txt"`, with the quotes literally as part of the arguments.
(Note that the quotes also won't protect the whitespace. An input string like `"foo bar"` would result in the two fields `"foo` and `bar"`. Also, the results of splitting would go through filename generation/globbing, so something like `foo*.txt` would be expanded then and there, not passed to `find` as-is.)

This is because word splitting is rather simple, it *only* splits on whitespace, it does *not* run the output through the full shell syntax parsing. (If it did, that would be actively dangerous, since it would also imply always recursively running any expansions, including command substitutions. It would be impossible to use the shell relative safely for arbitrary data.)

If you want to have the part from the file go though the full syntax processing, you'll have to run the command with `eval`, e.g.:

```
eval 'find "$path" -type f \( '"$(cat file)"' \)'
```

Here, after the outer shell processes the quotes and the command substitution, `eval` gets the following string, which is then processed as a shell command, including quote processing and all expansions.

```
find "$path" -type f \( -name "a.txt" -o -name "b.txt" \)
```

(Note that this means that if the file contains e.g. `"$(reboot)"`, that command will run. However, I left `"$path"` to be expanded by the inner shell, so that it will not be double-processed.)

You could do the above in multiple steps, e.g. by assigning the words from the file to an array with `eval`, and then using that array in the final command. The idea and the caveats are the same.

---

You might wish to reconsider the format of the file. Even e.g. putting each argument on a separate line (and nixing the quotes) would make it easier to parse.

E.g. if the file was:

```
-name
a.txt
-o
-name
foo bar.txt
```

You could do something like this, where `readarray` reads each input line to a separate array element:

```
#!/bin/bash
readarray -t args < file 
find "$path" -type f \( "${args[@]}" \)
```

(That's still limited in that it can't process filenames with newlines, but those are likely to be rarer, and would produce other issues too.)

Then again, if all you need is `-name` matches, you could have the file list only the patterns, and produce the `-o -name` boilerplate programmatically.

See also:

- https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting
- [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946/170373) (containing related issues and a generic example of building a command line to an array)
- [Build find command from arguments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/766709/170373) (containing a rather more to-the-point example of building a `find` command line)

Comment: Thank you!! :) The eval made it and it's finally worked for me, and I've accepted the answer.
I must also thank @J. Cravens for the time he spent with me and helped with the second answer

Amazing community! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Use:**

You need separate lines, and remove `-o` from the file, to make it easy.

```
find "$path" -type f $(sed '1q;d' filter_files) -o $(sed '2q;d' filter_files)
```

**or:**

Single string.

```
filter_conditions=$(<sed '1q;d' filter_files)
find_files=$(find "$path" -type f \( $filter_conditions \))
```

Comment: The OP needs to read `-name "a.txt" -o -name "b.txt"` from a file. They don't have two files, one named `a.txt` and one named `b.txt` with one file name in each, they have one file, named `filter_files` that contains the string `-name "a.txt" -o -name "b.txt"`.

Comment: @terdon Oh, okay.  If they are on separate lines, it's easy. `$(sed '1q;d' filter_files)` &  `$(sed '2q;d filter_files)`

Comment: But they aren't. Please read the question again, all the information is there. If you need to change the format of the file, that's fine, but please include the relevant commands in your answer, using the example files the OP provided.

Comment: That's not the idea, as @terdon mentioned, I don't know in advance the files a.txt/b.txt, they're just examples of the input I get.. maybe I need to reformat the file, I can do it, I eventually want to track files by a filter, and have a utility to track them.

The list of filters can be larger than 2, hope I didn't got misunderstood in the original post

Comment: @avij https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150858/find-command

Comment: @J.Cravens thank you very much, but I'm a noob here and got no reputation to join a chat :(

Comment: @avij I updated it for a single line input. :)